# How many values are allowed in a single INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

When I insert multiple rows into my SQL Server 2008 database table as such:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name, ID)
VALUES ('First',1),
('Second',2),
('Third',3),
('Fourth',4),
('Fifth',5)
```

How many of those values am I allowed to use in a single `INSERT INTO` statement?

Comment: @lad2025: Do you have any reference for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my testing, the limit is 1000 rows. Just tried inserting many rows and came up with this error:

> The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds
>   the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

It is actually documented [**here**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187905(v=sql.105).aspx):

> The maximum number of rows that can be inserted in a single INSERT
>   statement is 1000.

And [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/dd776382.aspx):

> The maximum number of rows that can be constructed by inserting rows
>   directly in the VALUES list is 1000. Error 10738 is returned if the
>   number of rows exceeds 1000 in that case.

Note that the 1000 rows limit is only for a single `VALUES` clause. As commented by [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) :

> It is not the `INSERT` statement that has a limit, it is the `VALUES`
>   clause. This is important if you do an insert that pulls data from
>   somewhere. That insert is only limited by memory/transaction
>   space/disk space.

Comment: @lad2025, apparently not. Just tried it on my machine, was able to insert 2k rows.

Comment: So with `UNION ALL` you are bounded with max batch  size `65,536 * Network Packet Size`.

Comment: It is not the `INSERT` statement that has a limit, it is the `VALUES` clause. This is important if you do an insert that pulls data from somewhere. That insert is only limited by memory/transaction space/disk space.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, just updated my answer with that info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> "The maximum number of rows in one VALUES clause is 1000"

It's not the INSERT statement that is limited to 1000 rows. [Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bff53b3d-bf50-413f-891e-75af427394e2/limit-to-number-of-insert-statements-or-values-clauses?forum=transactsql)

**EDIT:**

Create csv file (or some file with defined field delimiter and row delimiter) and use `BULK INSERT` option to load file to database. File can have 100000 rows; there won't be any problem of loading huge file using bulk upload.[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)